# Crystal Report in vb.net 2017 do not display data

Tags: crystal-reports

This is currently my problem. I used vb.net 2017 and database in xampp server. I watched a video from youtube and it says to connect it with ODBC connector. But all I can see from server explorer are tables only from my database. I cant see the columns under such tables. And when I run the program, crystal report does not display the data, only the column names. What am I gonna do? huhu help me pleeeaaase.

When i try to add data connection, this window shows no "MySQL Database". I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 and I installed mysql for visual studio 8.0
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsX3l.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you mind posting some code so we can take a look? Be sure to format the code inside of code blocks in the editor to make it easier to read! Good luck with finding your answer!

Comment: Sir, sorry I did not use any codes yet. I am just trying to first connect crystal report to a trial project so when I finally conected it, I will do the same process in my project. I just followed a tutorial on how to connect create a report.

Comment: I already solved the problem, just now haha. I uninstalled MySQL Connector 8.0 and changed it into ver 1.2.9 and restarted the computer. It worked!. :)